# Changing target android verison from 7.1 to 8.1 shows error(xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I created the application and it works fine for target andriod version 7.1 and target framework 8.1. There is no any error in my application. 
when i put the minimumSdk android version 4.4 and targeted android version 7.1. the program is absolutely fine.
But when i change the targeted android version to 8.1 and minimumsdk version 4.4  after debugging ,  it shows application break point error while clicking the button of that program.I am working on it for last two days but i didn't find any solution on it. 
I have updated my android sdk version 8.1 and its platform as well.

so i am very tensed on changing the API level 25 to 27?? 
I will be extremely thankful if get the solution.

Comment: Please add a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) about this issue.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT it gives the error like this  " Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code.

Comment: You could find the diagnostic build log in the Output Window.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. But  when i install 8.1 android version in my mobile it woks . . Thank you so much -York Shen